# Cannot draw multiple lines

Tags: d3.js

I have am trying to draw several lines on a single graph:

```
self.draw = function(data) {
    self.clear();
    self.createRanges(data);
    self.drawLines(data);
    self.drawAxes(data);
    self.drawLegend();
};

self.drawLines = function(data){
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(datum){
            return self.xRange(datum.classification);
        })
        .y(function(datum){
            return self.yRange(datum.value);
        })
        .interpolate("linear");
    self.vis.selectAll(".line").data(data).enter()
         .append("path")
             .attr("class", "line")
             .attr("d", line)
             .attr("stroke", "blue")
             .attr("stroke-width", 2)
             .attr("fill", "none");
};
```

Data looks like this:

```
var data = [
        {
            category: 0,
            classification: "10-09",
            value: 10.6
        }, {
            category: 1,
            classification: "10-09",
            value: 11.2
        },


        {
            category: 0,
            classification: "10-10",
            value: 10.3
        }, {
            category: 1,
            classification: "10-10",
            value: 13.0
        }
];
```

But no lines appear.  There are no errors, and the graph axes draw successfully.  I am able to do this with a single line using the entirety of `data` as the line's coordinates and appending it directly to `self.vis`, but when moving to the multi-line case no line is drawn.

Comment: Your data is only a single array, how do you want to get multiple lines from it?

Comment: Each category corresponds to a different line.  I will clarify that I know to some extent why i'm wrong, but I don't really know how to  go about implementing such a solution without iterating or doing something else like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't the right format to draw multiple lines directly; for that you need a nested structure. You can create this using [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest):

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.category; })
  .entries(data);
```

This then gives you something you can use directly to draw the lines like this:

```
vis.selectAll("path.line").data(nested)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnu7emhu/).